# nodejs and MongoDB's collection.find() does not respond

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, node-async

I have about 30,000 documents in a MongoDB collection. And have been stuck in developing a node.js script to retrieve only the records with a specific string key-value pair.

this query on MongoDB server returns me the exact results I've been looking for:

```
db.getCollection('posts').find({authorName: "Ashwin-kumar"})
```

Returns me about 33 documents instantly. Likewise I've about 40 authors with different names.

Here's my node.js script to retrieve posts by authorName (Yes, it is based on Name, a string, as there is no ID for these authors :( ):

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    request = require('request'),
    async = require("async"),
    assert = require('assert');
    _ = require('lodash'),
    MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

var db, postsCollection, postCol;

async.series([dbConnect, checkCollection, createMeta, dbClose], function(){
    console.log("Executed all calls in series.");
    process.exit(0);
});

function dbConnect(callback){
    MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/jPosts", function(pErr, pDb) {
        if(pErr) {
            console.dir(pDb);
            return 0;
        }
        db = pDb;
        callback();
    });
}

function dbClose(callback){
    db.close(true, function (err) {
        if (err) console.error(err);
        else console.log("close complete");
        callback();
    });
}

function checkCollection(callback) {
    db.collection('posts', function(err, collection) {});
    postsCollection = db.collection('posts');
    postCol = db.collection('posts');
    callback();
}

function createMeta(callback){
    var meta = [];
    postsCollection.aggregate([
        {
            $group : {_id : "$authorName"}
        }]).toArray(function(err, result) {
            assert.equal(err, null);
            async.forEachLimit(result, 1, function(pPost, callback) {
                getPosts(pPost._id, callback);
            }, function(err) {
                console.log(err);
                callback();
            });                
        });
}

function getPosts(pAuthor, callback){
    var cursor = postCol.find({ "authorName": pAuthor});
    cursor.toArray(function(err,items){
        if(err)
            callback(err);
           else
           callback(null, items);
        });
}
```

This does not seem to work for me. cursor.toArray() does nothing but wait forever. Is it because of too many fields in each document?

I tried to get the count of the documents the cursor fetched and it works well.

```
function getPosts(pAuthor, callback){
    var cursor = postCol.find({ "authourName": pAuthor});
    cursor.count().then(function(items_count) {
        console.log(items_count);
        callback();
    });        
}
```

Also, I tried the cursor's .each method to iterate the documents fetched. But no luck yet.

```
function getPosts(pAuthor, callback){
    var cursor = postCol.find({ "authourName": pAuthor});
    cursor.each(function(err, doc) {
        assert.equal(err, null);
       if (doc != null) {
          console.dir(doc);
       } else {
           console.log(err);
       }  
   });
}
```

Am I missing something here? What else can be done to make this work? Is there any issues with the way I'm using async?

P.S: The idea here is to query the dump and generate the PDF's for authours in the jPost collection.

P.S 2: Here's a sample document

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("571d36b55672f713fe346a66"),
    "id" : 56517,
    "authorName" : "Ashwin-kumar",
    "comment_count" : 380,
    "tagline" : "... Opinions you don't really need",
    "vote_count" : 5152,
    "exclusive" : null,
    "post": [
    ],
    "post_comments" : [ 
        //comment_count objects
    ],
    "date" : "2016-03-27"
}
```

(I've omitted post & post_comments parts for brevity.)

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
var collection = db.collection("collection_name");
collection.find({authourName: "Ashwin-kumar"}).toArray(function (err,items) {
     if (err) {
        console.dir(err);
     } else {
        //do something with items array
        console.dir(items);
     }
});
```

Comment: where "collection_name" is the name of your collection

Answer (score 0):

Did you check what is the value of pAuthor in getPosts? Because when you do aggregation, you receive a collection of objects with _id field (not authourName), so you should do:

```
// not sure why you need meta array, at least it's not used in the code you provided
meta.push({
   author: pPost._id
});
getPosts(pPost._id, callback);
```

Comment: Meta array is used else where for a different purpose. And yes, the aggregation return list of authors and post count

Comment: Right, pPost._id is what I use in my actual code. When cleaning up the entire functions to post here I replaced pPost._id with the authorName.

Comment: Ah ok, which version of async are you using? Because there is no forEachLimit in the doc https://github.com/caolan/async, I use async.eachLimit for the same purpose. However, the version of library is unlikely to be the reason of the problem.

Comment: Using v2.0.0-rc.3. Thanks for the heads up. Seems like forEachLimit is deprecated and falls back to eachLimit (I need to verify this). This should not be the issue with collection.find({}).toArray(). toArray() becomes unresponsive

Comment: Does getPosts stuck on some particular authorName query or immediately on the first one? If on the first one, what if you try to use the hardcoded "Ashwin-kumar" value in getPosts, just to check if the query will still be stuck?

Comment: Immediately on the first one. Yes, I did try hard coding the authorName and it did not change a thing. It still hangs on the first one.

Comment: This may be of some use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36264331/nodejs-server-hangs-on-find-query-of-mongodb-on-simultanious-requests

Comment: Hmm. Thanks for that. Have the same issue but my mongoDb node module is "2.1.16"

Comment: I guess I figured out the issue. The .find() on the collection was called on the same connection while still the aggregator iterator was in process. This may be the problem but I'm not sure. so I create a new connection everytime in the getPosts() method and ran find on it's collection and that seems to have solved the issue. I'm still not convinced it is the right way to do it